# What are unique properties that only apply to functions of 4 dimensions and up?

Tags: real-analysis

Chaos in dynamical systems is often attributed as a relationship for 3 or more dimensions.

Are there unique patterns, structures or ideas that can only occur for parameterized paths that are 4 dimensions and up, like for a 4 dimensional function $S(x(t),y(t),z(t),f(t))$?

Comment: Chaos is present even in 1-d (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map)

Comment: But the relationship between the variables needs to be three dimensional or higher. You can have multi-dimensional relationships between multiple variables on a 1-D surface.

Comment: So for logistic map, what are the multidimensional relationships?

Comment: From the looks of it, $x$ $r$ and $n.$ Keep in mind that the curve having a fractal hausdorff dimension alone does not necessarily imply chaos.